# HTML Bootstrap Carousel (carousel-control)

Tags: html, css

About the issue that currently facing is that for Bootstrap Carousel (from w3school) , there is a problem for carousel-control.

Problem that i am facing is that when i have enter hyperlink for the image , the carousel-control are larger then the image itself (screenshot below).

> Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r4wh2f

**Codes for my bootstrap carousel**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12 col-md-12 banner-section">
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
                <a href="facebook.com"><picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 900px)" srcset="image/banner01small.jpg">
            <img src="image/banner01" alt="banner" style="z-index:1" class="img-fluid">
        </picture></a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
                <a href="instagram.com"><picture>
            <source media="(max-width: 900px)" srcset="image/banner02small.jpg">
            <img src="image/banner02" alt="banner" style="z-index:1" class="img-fluid">
        </picture></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Vadivel123/e7pthd3n/)

Just Added CSS below mentioned code

```
a.carousel-control {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 47%;
}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the fast reply. but after placing the code this is the new problem occur. (Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/r4wpb3)

Comment: Can you see my demo link?

Comment: Thank you , tried to modify and everything works now . Thanks for the fast solution

Answer (score 0):

This is because the controls are also using the anchor tag and is conflicting with the same.you can add additional css to control anchor tags of the carousal and it will work fine.

All the best :)